# Java: how to format string with logging-like pattern?

Tags: java, string, logging, formatting, string-formatting

Sometimes it's required to compose a string using logging-like pattern:

> Something went wrong, detailA={}, detailB={}

but not in order to log it, but for other purposes (e.g. send over network).

Sometimes it's causing code duplication, like this:

```
logger.info("Something went wrong, detailA={}, detailB={}", detailA, detailB));

otherSystem.info(String.format("Something went wrong, detailA=%s, detailB=%s",
  detailA, detailB);
```

Which is highly inconvenient and error-prone. How to format a string using logging pattern and logging-like API?

Comment: No good ideas, maybe: could it make sense to create a wrapper for your logging calls - one method that takes message and substitution arguments ... and then calls logger.info and otherSystem.info?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you using `slf4j`, you can use its `MessageFormatter.arrayFormat` which returns a `FormattingTuple`,

```
FormattingTuple ft = MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(format, argArray);
```

And then convert it to a string.

```
String msg = ft.getMessage();
```

Which means you can add a utility method for that

```
static String format(String format, String...params) {
    FormattingTuple ft = MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(format, params);
    String message = ft.getMessage();
    return message;
}

System.out.println(format("hi {}, you {}", "there", "rock"));
```